# WPF: define image background in Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I add a URI image to be used as the background for this style? Is it possible?
Using URI like: "/WpfAPP10;component/Interface.png"

```
<Style x:Key="mega" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button"  >
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

- add image to your project
- set build action to "Resource"

use as

```
<Style x:Key="mega" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button"  >
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="/WpfAPP10;component/Interface.png"/>
</Style>
```

or

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Interface.png"/>
```

or

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="pack://application:,,,/WpfAPP10;component/Interface.png""/>
```

this will set the desired image to the background

Comment: <Style x:Key="mega" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"  TargetType="Button"  >
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="/mega;component/uif/yellow.png"/>
        </Style>

Comment: Error: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.DeferredBinaryDeserializerExtension' threw an exception.

Comment: you need to make sure the uri `/WpfAPP10;component/Interface.png` represent a valid image. make sure after you add image to your project the build action is "Resource" you can simply refer image as `"Interface.png"` or full path as `pack://application:,,,/WpfAPP10;component/Interface.png"` also

Answer (score 1):

This is what has worked.

```
<Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/uif\yellow.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```